# Recursive findIndices

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have been tasked to write a function which is basically same as findIndices but in a recursive way. So far I have managed to make this:

```
getIndicesFor :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
getIndicesFor x (y:ys) = (fst (head(filter ((x y).snd) as ))):getIndicesFor x ys where
    as = (zip [0..] (y:ys))
```

But this results in an error saying: "Could't match expected type `b0 -> Bool' with actual type`Bool'". And I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be written using do notation. I don't feel bad presenting this because **you probably won't get credit for submitting this** as an answer, because it does not use explicit recursion:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

getIndicesFor :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
getIndicesFor f xs = do
  (n, x) <- zip [0..] xs
  guard (f x)
  return n

-- in fact you could write it compactly as a list comprehension
-- though I personally avoid list comprehensions, as I find "do" syntax clearer
-- getIndicesFor f xs = [n | (n, x) <- zip [0..] xs, f x]
```

Testing...

```
ghci> take 5 $ getIndicesFor even [0 ..]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
ghci> take 5 $ getIndicesFor even [2, 4 ..]
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

So the concept is simple, right? pick an element from the list, test it with the specified function, and add its index to the list if it passes.

If you must write this function using explicit recursion, then you will need to handle the two cases differently: does this particular element pass or fail the test? If it passes, then you add its index to the list of results. If it fails, *then you don't*. This is the main problem with what I see in your code right now.

```
getIndicesFor x (y:ys) = blahblah : getIndicesFor x ys
```

You *always* add *something*, whether or not `y` passes or fails the test. This is wrong. Try using an `if` or `case` statement to differentiate the two different cases. Also, if you are using explicit recursion, then you must handle the empty list case explicitly:

```
getIndicesFor x [] = ???
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I can see the type error. You use the expression

```
((x y).snd)
```

as the filtering function, which ought to have type `(Int, a) -> Bool`. However, you have

```
x :: a -> Bool
y :: a
```

which makes `(x y) :: Bool`. But you're trying to post-compose that thing to `snd` to build a filtering function, which would only work if it was a function of type `something -> Bool`. That's what the error message is moaning about.

In the context of the problem, it's not clear to me why you would want to use `y` to build a filtering function, when `y` is just one of the elements of the list that you're investigating. Nor is clear to me why you need to break the list up as `(y:ys)` in any case.

Your attempt has quite a lot of the correct logic to it, but the 'plumbing' needs work. Once you've sorted out your filtering function, you'll need to look at the way you handle the output of `filter` to get the data you want.

Now, if I were writing this program, I'd seriously consider using [list comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension): if you haven't seen them, it's worth checking them out.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have mixed up findIndices and elemIndices, so that probably changes the whole question. the reason I broke the list up as (y:ys) is because I was taught to do that when making a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes.

- If you need to write function same as `elemIndices`, your `getIndicesFor` should have same signature `:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]`
- Looking at `filter ((x y).snd)`. Seems like you want to filter pairs, where second element is equal to `x`. To figured out that second tuple element is equal to x we might use lambda function like `(\tuple -> snd tuple == x)`
- `(y:ys)` used twice, so you can use `list@(y:ys)` and then call it `list` instead of `(y:ys)`.
- It's better to use `$` instead of brackets mess.
- When you're defining recursive function you shouldn't forget about matching empty list case.
- Be careful with using `head` function. It's unsafe because it can return error exception if list-argument is empty. `[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`
- At current state your function returns element (because of using `fst`), not it index. And you should pay attention at fact, that index of `x` element in `(y:ys)` can be different from index of that element in original list.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have mixed up findIndices and elemIndices, so that probably changes the whole question.

Comment: The `Eq` constraint is unnecessary, since his `getIndeciesFor` takes in an arbitrary function which decides whether the element is "correct" or not. It's confusing, though, because he names it `x`.

Answer (score -2):

```
getIndicesFor :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
getIndicesFor f xs = map fst (filter (f.snd) as) 
    where
      as = zip [0..] xs
```

if use as = (zip [0..] xs) then you have no way recursive define getIndicesFor direct

rewrite by use helper function

```
getIndicesFor :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
getIndicesFor f xs = aux as 
    where
      as = zip [0..] xs
      aux [] = []
      aux (x:xs) =
        if (f.snd) x then
           (fst x) : aux xs
        else
           aux xs
```

Comment: Help answer whether this is not known, the policy question of recursive definitions can not think. To define such a function in the form once I suggest considering whether it be rewritten in a recursive form. To rewrite the recursive form seems to require a helper function.